# Dynamically overriding typeclass methods

Tags: haskell, dynamic, typeclass

Suppose I have a data type `T` that has an equality function and a list:

```hs
data T a = T (a -> a -> Bool) [a]
```

How can I use a predefined function that requires `Eq a`, but uses the equality function in `T`?

As an example:

```hs
elemIndices' x (T eq xs) = (???? Data.List.elemIndices) x xs
-- same as Data.List.elemIndices:
elemIndices' 1 (T (==) [0,1,2,1,3]) == [1,3]
-- "inverse" of Data.List.elemIndices:
elemIndices' 1 (T (/=) [0,1,2,1,3]) == [0,2,4]
```

I would prefer not to re-implement the functions like `Data.List.elemIndices` above.

Comment: In general, you can not call an `Eq a => ...` function providing your own equality operator `a->a->Bool`. Haskell typeclasses guarantee coherence, meaning that all `Eq a=>` constraints will see the same implementation of equality, and this would be easy to break if we could choose our own. Coherence is important e.g. for `Set a` which requires `Ord a` to perform insertions: if we could use different orderings on each insertion, we would break the internal BST invariants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @chi notes in a comment, there's no direct way to "override" an `Eq a` constraint with your own implementation, as it would be an unsafe operation.  This is why most `Data.List` functions that use an `Eq` constraint (e.g., `group`) also have a separate version where the equality function can be supplied by the caller (e.g., `groupBy`).  @cafce25 has pointed out in their answer that `findIndices` will work well as a more general `elemIndices`.

More generally, the usual, safe way of calling a function with a different `Eq a` instance is to introduce a `newtype` to replace the `Eq` instance.  This works fine when you have a fixed alternative equality function:

```
myEq :: Int -> Int -> Bool
myEq x y = even x == even y

newtype MyInt = MyInt Int
instance Eq MyInt where
  (==) == coerce myEq

elemIndices' :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
elemIndices' x xs = elemIndices (MyInt x) (coerce xs)

main = print $ elemIndices' 2 [1..10]  -- indices of all even elements
```

but adapting it to your situation, where the equality operation is determined at runtime, is a bit of a challenge.

I think the best you can do is construct a data type that pairs each element with a copy of the equality function, and give it an appropriate `Eq` instance:

```
data WithEq a = WithEq (a -> a -> Bool) a
instance Eq (WithEq a) where
  WithEq eq x == WithEq _ y = eq x y
```

Then, you can write:

```
data T a = T (a -> a -> Bool) [a]

elemIndices' :: a -> T a -> [Int]
elemIndices' x (T eq xs) = elemIndices (withEq x) (map withEq xs)
  where withEq = WithEq eq
```

and, for example:

```
main = print $ elemIndices' 2 (T (\x y -> even x == even y) [1..10])
```

Obviously, there are some potential efficiency problems here, though GHC may do a reasonable job optimization away some of the extra copies of the equality function.

In the example above, GHC optimizes the code to equivalent of:

```
go x i | x > 10    = []
       | even x    = i : go (x+1) (i+1)
       | otherwise = go (x+1) (i+1)

main = print $ go 1 0
```

with the integers unboxed, so no time or space is wasted making copies of the equality function, and it's fully lifted out of the data structure so it can be inlined into the rest of the code.

So, even though this is a little ugly, it seems like a workable solution.

Full example:

```
import Data.List

data WithEq a = WithEq (a -> a -> Bool) a
instance Eq (WithEq a) where
  WithEq eq x == WithEq _ y = eq x y

data T a = T (a -> a -> Bool) [a]

elemIndices' :: a -> T a -> [Int]
elemIndices' x (T eq xs) = elemIndices (withEq x) (map withEq xs)
  where withEq = WithEq eq

main :: IO ()
main = print $ elemIndices' 2 (T (\x y -> even x == even y) [1..10])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `findIndices` to define `elemIndices'`:

```hs
elemIndices' x (T eq xs) = Data.List.findIndices (eq x) xs
```